# How to execute one single test using Test::Class

Tags: perl, automation

I had the following code which has many test Functions

```
package A;
{
BEGIN { $ENV{DIE_ON_FAIL} = 1 }

    sub test_168 : Test(no_plan){
    print("168");
    }

    sub test_169 : Test(no_plan){
    print("169");
    }
1;
}
```

If invoke this module using Test::Class all the testMethods are Executed. Is there any solution to execute the required methods only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [TEST_METHOD](http://search.cpan.org/~adie/Test-Class-0.36/lib/Test/Class.pm#RUNNING_INDIVIDUAL_TESTS) environment variable to restrict the testing to a single method (`TEST_METHOD='test_168'`) or all methods that match a regex (`TEST_METHOD='test_16.'`)

Comment: But the Regexp is not working. It says that no test are exceuted

Comment: If Multiple test modules are there how to set them in Test_Method

Comment: To whom it may concern: To run multiple test methods, I have to specify the exact name of the test method(s) in a compiled regex, concatenated with `|`. Example: `$ENV{TEST_METHOD} = qr/tests_is_online|tests_is_notnull/;`